# How do I start a batch file minimized

Tags: batch-file, windows-10

I would like to know how to start a batch file minimized without creating a shortcut.

I also want the code on how to relaunch a batch file minimized without using a VBS

So if anyone knows how to start the batch file minimized from the first launch that would be great.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @fpmurphy windows 10

Answer (score 1):

By adding some `powershell`

```
@echo off
echo This batch will minimize and return to normal in 5 second intervals.
timeout /t 5 >nul
powershell -window minimized -command ""
timeout /t 5 >nul
powershell -window normal -command ""
echo and We're back..
```

if you want to use nothing other than batch, then the **wrong** way, as we do not really `start` batch files, would be:

```
start "" /min "batchfilename.cmd"
```

If you run this from another batch file, that batch file will remain open, unless you exit it. So in order to run it in your actual batch file, it would be something like:

```
echo Hello!
if not DEFINED IS_MINIMIZED set IS_MINIMIZED=1 && start "" /min "%~0" %* && exit
timeout /t 10
exit
```

The timeout here just gives you some time to see the window running minimized.

Answer (score 0):

try with [this](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/getCmdPID.bat) and [this](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/c/windowMode.bat):

```
@echo off

echo self minimizing
call getCmdPid.bat
call windowMode.bat -pid %errorlevel% -mode minimized

echo --other commands--
pause
```